# How do I use the mongoose-sequence project in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-sequence

I am trying to build a REST API server with an auto-incrementing field with Mongoose, Express, and TypeScript using the [mongoose-sequence project](https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-sequence/blob/master/test/sequence.test.js).  (This project seems like the most popular and supported of the ones out there.)

I have run `npm install --save @types\mongoose-sequence` to import the types for TypeScript.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to correctly make use of it.

The code in the README says to do the following:

```
const AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose);
```

How does that translate into TypeScript?

Can someone explain the basics to get me rolling?

Comment: `import Inc from "mongoose-sequence";
 const AutoIncrement = Inc(mongoose)
`;

Comment: @ShanonJackson -- Thanks for your interest in my problem.  However, the `import` statement you gave won't compile.  :-(

Comment: it will compile, its the equivalent to require syntax and also how you import someones default export. The issue may be that the typings aren't working correctly. try add // @ts-ignore above it and see if it compiles/works if it does its a typings issue

Comment: @ShanonJackson  Where is `Inc` exported by mongoose-sequence?

Comment: @ShanonJackson  I get `TypeError: mongoose_sequence_1.Inc is not a function` even with the @ts-ignore

Comment: The typings say its a function so its typed possibly for the wrong version of the library. Reading through the typings it says the default export is a function that takes a mongoose schema NOT mongoose itself.

Give me a second to figure this out

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me both on a type-level and a value level.

```
import Inc from "mongoose-sequence";
import { userSchema } from "../SOME-MONGOOSE-SCHEMA.ts";
const AutoIncrement = Inc(userSchema);
```

Note that this contradicts the documentation, which says you should pass it a mongoose instance but the typings say it takes a mongoose schema.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the following based on Shanon's answer (**passing the mongoose instance instead of a schema**):

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
// @ts-ignore
import Inc from "mongoose-sequence";

const AutoIncrement = Inc(mongoose); 

// define your schema

UserSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, { id: "user_id", inc_field: "id" });
```

I've tried many approaches and realised that using types with `@types/mongoose-sequence` (version "^3.0.6") breaks the code becauese it says that the library exports a void function and of course you cannot use a void value later. So that's why the `@ts-ignore` is present.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use the mongoose-sequence for Nest.js

```
import mongoose, { Connection } from 'mongoose'
import { MatchEntity } from './entities/match.entity'
import { DB_CONNECTION, MATCH_MODEL, MATCH_NAME } from '../constants'

export const matchesProviders = [
  {
    provide: MATCH_MODEL,
    useFactory: (connection: Connection) => {
      const inc = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose)
      MatchEntity.plugin(inc, { inc_field: 'id' })
      return connection.model(MATCH_NAME, MatchEntity)
    },
    inject: [DB_CONNECTION],
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

mongoose-auto-increment package could be used here for the same object as follows

```
 import { createConnection, Schema } from 'mongoose';
 import autoIncrement from 'mongoose-auto-increment';

 const connection = await mongoose.createConnection(DATABASE_URL);
 autoIncrement.initialize(connection);

 const modelSchema = new Schema({...});

 modelSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Model');

 export default model('Model', modelSchema);
```

mongoose.createConnection() could be imported if the data base connection was established in another definition.